# Como puedo crear esete flitro en mi bot de telegram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

estoy creando un filtro de en mi bot con la librería de telegram pero cuando ejecuto el comando no hace nada /buy_w01 y cuando lo uso de esta manera si funciona /Buy_01

```
MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r"\/buy_\d+$"), buy)

def buy(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    weapon = update.message.text.replace("/buy_", "")
    print(weapon)
return
```

Comment: `regex(r"\/buy_\d+$")` ¿Qué dice este regex?

Comment: no me muestra ningún error , y no hace nada , pero cuando solo coloco /Buy_01  si me muestra en print

Comment: pues lógico, eso es lo que hace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r"\/buy_\d+$"), buy)
```

En este regex hay `buy_\d+$` esta parte `\d+$` dice dígitos.

> cuando ejecuto el comando no hace nada /buy_w01

Esto no funciona porque luego del guión hay una letra `w`, por lo tanto no pasa.

> si funciona /Buy_01

Esto sí funciona porque luego del guíon bajo hay dígitos.

**Actualización**

Este regex `\/buy_\w+$` trae palabras, aquí un ejemplo:

```
/buy_2sdfsdf
/buy_ew2
/buy_www
/buy_3323
/buy_2 asdasd
```

El último caso no lo considera por el espacio en blanco que hay entre `/buy_2` y `asdasd`.

Para aprender expresiones regulares, aquí un buen sitio: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Vale entiendo , y cómo sería para que lea las letra y los números ?

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias me funcionó